# How to do a pure css parallax scrolling?

Tags: css

I tried it but does not work as expected. please explain me what I need to add to make it working! I don't want to use any JS code.

```
body {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective:3px;
}

#a {
  height:300px;
  transform: translateZ(-1);
}
#b {
  height:350px;
  transform: translateZ(-2);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8uor3d07/

What must I add to have the parallax effect using CSS3 between div a and div b ?

Comment: You may find your solution [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to stack elements on the z axis. This still requires a bit of touch up but the main effect is there.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: red;
}

#aaa {
  height: 300px;
  background: url("http://www.palmbeachbookfestival.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/palm-tree-beach-island-blue-ocean-sand_095462.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

#bbb {
  height: 750px;
  background: #131418;
  z-index: 2;
}

#ccc {
  height: 750px;
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/800/900");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 3;
}

#ddd {
  height: 750px;
  background: #131418;
  z-index: 4;
}

#eee {
  height: 750px;
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/700/900");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 5;
}

div p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="aaa">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, soleat vulputate ei nec, at sea persecuti reprehendunt, solum essent incorrupte has no. Munere laoreet alienum ut his, est sint primis cu. Id case primis facilisis eos, pro ut mutat luptatum pertinax. Mea an possit delenit.
    At nec legere adversarium. Quem deleniti at sit, ei duo decore democritum. Ex per dico offendit accommodare, mea quidam possim numquam ut. Te commune disputando pri, vis nonumy nostro commune te. Id mel unum porro, aliquip patrioque sed ad, vitae
    eripuit pertinacia pri ne. Tantas soleat vulputate in sea.</p>
</div>
<div id="bbb">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, soleat vulputate ei nec, at sea persecuti reprehendunt, solum essent incorrupte has no. Munere laoreet alienum ut his, est sint primis cu. Id case primis facilisis eos, pro ut mutat luptatum pertinax. Mea an possit delenit.
    At nec legere adversarium. Quem deleniti at sit, ei duo decore democritum. Ex per dico offendit accommodare, mea quidam possim numquam ut. Te commune disputando pri, vis nonumy nostro commune te. Id mel unum porro, aliquip patrioque sed ad, vitae
    eripuit pertinacia pri ne. Tantas soleat vulputate in sea.</p>
</div>
<div id="ccc">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, soleat vulputate ei nec, at sea persecuti reprehendunt, solum essent incorrupte has no. Munere laoreet alienum ut his, est sint primis cu. Id case primis facilisis eos, pro ut mutat luptatum pertinax. Mea an possit delenit.
    At nec legere adversarium. Quem deleniti at sit, ei duo decore democritum. Ex per dico offendit accommodare, mea quidam possim numquam ut. Te commune disputando pri, vis nonumy nostro commune te. Id mel unum porro, aliquip patrioque sed ad, vitae
    eripuit pertinacia pri ne. Tantas soleat vulputate in sea.</p>
</div>
<div id="ddd">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, soleat vulputate ei nec, at sea persecuti reprehendunt, solum essent incorrupte has no. Munere laoreet alienum ut his, est sint primis cu. Id case primis facilisis eos, pro ut mutat luptatum pertinax. Mea an possit delenit.
    At nec legere adversarium. Quem deleniti at sit, ei duo decore democritum. Ex per dico offendit accommodare, mea quidam possim numquam ut. Te commune disputando pri, vis nonumy nostro commune te. Id mel unum porro, aliquip patrioque sed ad, vitae
    eripuit pertinacia pri ne. Tantas soleat vulputate in sea.</p>
</div>
<div id="eee">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, soleat vulputate ei nec, at sea persecuti reprehendunt, solum essent incorrupte has no. Munere laoreet alienum ut his, est sint primis cu. Id case primis facilisis eos, pro ut mutat luptatum pertinax. Mea an possit delenit.
    At nec legere adversarium. Quem deleniti at sit, ei duo decore democritum. Ex per dico offendit accommodare, mea quidam possim numquam ut. Te commune disputando pri, vis nonumy nostro commune te. Id mel unum porro, aliquip patrioque sed ad, vitae
    eripuit pertinacia pri ne. Tantas soleat vulputate in sea.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to control the scoll speed of a div. Look my new jsfiddle , it does not work for the moment. What must i add ? https://jsfiddle.net/8uor3d07/1/